# Angular 7 http (post) with authorization headers -> Error 500

Tags: angular, api, post, authorization

I've got a problem in implementing authorization in an Angular 7 app. I send data to an API (PHP) via HttpClient.post and without adding headers everything works fine. If I add any headers f.e.

```
headers = headers.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.user.token);
```

the request is sent via OPTIONS instead of POST and the server responds with a 500-error. I've successfully tried a test with jQuery.ajax. There's a before-send handler for adding the headers.

I've also tried to use an Interceptor for the request, but the problem is the same. Does anyone has an idea, what I can try to solve this?

Comment: Does it throw any error related to CORS? Is your Web API enabled with CORS to accept headers?

Comment: Yes the console shows 2 CORS issues:
(1) Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing and (2) CORS request did not succeed
 But the web API (PHP) has the `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` I wonder why the send method changes from POST to OPTIONS if I add a header in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It must be with CORS settings. Add the following settings in the web service, where '*' includes OPTIONS, GET, POST & other HTTP verbs.

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *